# Footnote design CSS: vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

Hello: I am trying to style footnotes in CSS and I have the following CSS code:

```css
.post-content sup a.footnote {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    min-width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    background: #f4f5f6;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #abb7b7
}

.post-content sup a.footnote:hover {
    background: #abb7b7;
    color: #fff
}

.post-content .footnotes {
    margin-top: 40px
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .post-content .footnotes {
        margin-top: 60px
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1220px) {
    .post-content .footnotes {
        margin-top: 80px
    }
}

.post-content .footnotes ol {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: footnotes
}

.post-content .footnotes ol li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    counter-increment: footnotes
}

.post-content .footnotes ol li:before {
    content: counter(footnotes);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    background: #f4f5f6;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    color: #abb7b7
}

.post-content .footnotes ol li p {
    display: inline;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px
}

.post-content .footnotes ol li p a.reversefootnote {
    border-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: sub
}
```

The idea is that, when I display a footnote, the numbers show up in a circle that references to the footnote, so that when I insert the following HTML code:

```html
<p>Some text<sup id="fnref:1" role="doc-noteref"><a href="#fn:1" class="footnote">1</a></sup>.</p>
```

Having the following footnote:

```html
<div class="footnotes" role="doc-endnotes">
  <ol>
    <li id="fn:1" role="doc-endnote">
      <p>Some footnote.&nbsp;<a href="#fnref:1" class="reversefootnote" role="doc-backlink">↩</a></p>
    </li>
    ...
  </ol>
</div>
```

The footnotes are displayed as I explained above. However, I end up with the following result:

[image: Footnote ref]

[image: Footnote]

How can I fix it so that the numbers are centered on the circle?

Thanks :)

> Here is a link to the issue: https://mianfg.me/2019/12/12/test

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for the issue and post it here?

Comment: Start by specifying a `line-height` for your circles.

Comment: @CBroe can you show me how?

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram I put a link on the question to my personal website, emulating the issue (note that I have additional CSS). I hope that's equivalent to the fiddle :)

Comment: That emulation of the issue on your site will be gone once the problem is fixed, so that would leave your question without proper context then. You need to provide a proper [mre] directly in your question. See also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the line-height to be equal to the height, the text will be now be in the center vertically. Since you have also used `text-align: center;`, that takes care of the horizontal alignment in this case.

```
.post-content .footnotes ol li:before {
    content: counter(footnotes);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0 3px;
    background: #f4f5f6;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    color: #abb7b7
}
```

Comment: I just checked it on your website itself.

Comment: Yes sorry and one last thing: When I do that the text line (the one where the number is located) is slightly displaced. How can I fix that?

Comment: Updated the answer, observe the padding value